# Print to the console when my bot leaves a server

Tags: python, discord.py

I have recently released a discord bot and I want to know whenever it is kicked from a server. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`on_guild_remove`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_remove) event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    print(f"Bot has left the {guild.name} server")
    # whatever here
```